# programming logic! :O

Tags: c#, ssis

Stumped for want of a seemingly reasonable programming logic..

Am inside a script task of SSIS. Need to do some data tranformations..as below..

```
switch(LeadTime)
{

case: 1

WM1 = DAY1
WM2 = DAY2
WM3 = DAY3
WM4 = DAY4
WM5 = DAY5
WM6 = DAY6
WM7 = DAY7


case: 2

WM1 = DAY1 + DAY2
WM2 = DAY2 + DAY3
WM3 = DAY3 + DAY4
WM4 = DAY4 + DAY5
WM5 = DAY5 + DAY6
WM6 = DAY6 + DAY7
WM7 = DAY7 + DAY1


case: 3


WM1 = DAY1 + DAY2 + DAY3
WM2 = DAY2 + DAY3 + DAY4
WM3 = DAY3 + DAY4 + DAY5
WM4 = DAY4 + DAY5 + DAY6
WM5 = DAY5 + DAY6 + DAY7
WM6 = DAY6 + DAY7 + DAY1
WM7 = DAY7 + DAY1 + DAY2


..................

case: 7 

WM1 = DAY1 + DAY2 + DAY3 + DAY4 + DAY5 + DAY6 + DAY7
WM2 = DAY2 + DAY3 + DAY4 + DAY5 + DAY6 + DAY7 + DAY1 
WM3 = DAY3 + DAY4 + DAY5 + DAY6 + DAY7 + DAY1 + DAY2 
WM4 = DAY4 + DAY5 + DAY6 + DAY7 + DAY1 + DAY2 + DAY3 
WM5 = DAY5 + DAY6 + DAY7 + DAY1 + DAY2 + DAY3 + DAY4 
WM6 = DAY6 + DAY7 + DAY1 + DAY2 + DAY3 + DAY4 + DAY5 
WM7 = DAY7 + DAY1 + DAY2 + DAY3 + DAY4 + DAY5 + DAY6 


}
```

How can I build a loop around this to make it good programming? Am at a loss because it adds from both ends after the mid-value..

this is all I could do! :O

```
case: 7

for(int i=0;i<LeadTime;i++)
{
WM1 += Array[i];
WM2 += Array[i];
...
WM7 += Array[i];
}
```

Comment: FYI, your `case 7` are all mathematically identical.

Comment: yes Daniel..this is just an illustration of the prob.

Comment: Removed 'functional-programming' tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work for all cases (assuming arrays are zero based):

```
for(int i=0;i<LeadTime;i++)
{
  WM1 += Array[(0+i)%7];
  WM2 += Array[(1+i)%7];
  ...
  WM7 += Array[(6+i)%7];
}
```

Comment: i will accept this as what i want..! elegant.. simple n easy for my old rusty brain!!   thanks all for your answers.. this was fantastic response.. feel free to post if you would like more..! so interesting!!!

Answer (score 6):

You can use modulo to make the wrap around. This should work for all:

```
WM = new int[7];
for (int i = 0; i < LeadTime; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < WM.Length; j++) {
    WM[j] += Array[(i + j) % 7];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is create a function that you can call for the different cases.

```
function foo(int LeadTime) {  
  for(int i=0; i < LeadTime; i++){  
      int k = i;  
      for (int j = 0; j < LeadTime; j++){  
          if (k > 7) {  k = 1; }  
          wm[i] += day[k];  
          k++;  
      }  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this code real quick. Bascially you're going to have to do a nested loop

```
string[] days = new string[] { "DAY1", "DAY2", "DAY3", "DAY4", "DAY5", "DAY6", "DAY7" };

            List<string> res = new List<string>();
            res.Add(string.Empty);

            int Leadtime = 7;

            for (int i = 1; i <= Leadtime; i++)
            {
                res.Add(string.Empty);
                int tmp = i + Leadtime - 1;

                for (int x = i; x <= tmp; x++)
                {
                    if (x > Leadtime) { x = 1; tmp = i-1; }
                    res[i] += " " + days[x-1];
                }

            }

            foreach (string s in res)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

results:

```
DAY1 DAY2 DAY3 DAY4 DAY5 DAY6 DAY7
DAY2 DAY3 DAY4 DAY5 DAY6 DAY7 DAY1
DAY3 DAY4 DAY5 DAY6 DAY7 DAY1 DAY2
DAY4 DAY5 DAY6 DAY7 DAY1 DAY2 DAY3
DAY5 DAY6 DAY7 DAY1 DAY2 DAY3 DAY4
DAY6 DAY7 DAY1 DAY2 DAY3 DAY4 DAY5
DAY7 DAY1 DAY2 DAY3 DAY4 DAY5 DAY6
```

Comment: looking at the question again, I don't think my code as-is solves the exact problem since i'm adding all days. The question shows some days being skipped depending on the lead time. My code only solves for "case 7"